# Replacing HTML tag without changing the value

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to change html tags.

**`<b>Text goes here<b>`** must be replaced to **`<h1>Text goes here</h1>`**

PS: Yes, `<b>` tag has no closing slash.

I tried this one: **`<b>(.*?)<b>`** to **`<h1>(.*?)</h2>`** but output was `<h1>(.*?)</h1>`

Is there any way to change HTML tags without changing the value between the tags?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), like so:

- `<b>(.*?)<b>` -> `<h1>\1</h1>`

And then perhaps:

- `<b><h1>` -> `<h1>`
- `<b></h1>` -> `</h1>`

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you.